# Convert plenty of jpeg images to png in batch

Tags: python, png, jpeg, image-conversion

For work, I need to convert about 200 jpeg images to png. I've tried PIL but I've no idea how to solve this problem. Any ideas?

```
import cv2
import glob
i=0

images = glob.glob("*.jpg")

for i in images:
    print("start")
    img = cv2.imread(images, 1)  
    cv2.imwrite(images, img, [cv2.IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION, 1])
    print("end")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing list of images to `cv2.imread()` and also there is an error in `cv2.imwrite()`.

Try this:

```
import cv2
import glob
i=0

images = glob.glob("*.jpg")

for i in images:
    print("start")
    img = cv2.imread(i, 1)  
    cv2.imwrite(i.split('.')[0]+'.png', img, [cv2.IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION, 1])
    print("end")
```

Comment: Well, I don't understand why I need to write <<i.split('.')[0]+'.png'>> in order to work

Comment: Welcome. i.split('.')[0]+'.png'  has nothing to do with your solution. I just used it to create an image of the same name but with png format.

Comment: You can add any name you want. It's solely up to you.

Comment: Thanks! How do I search for docs online about cv2? Maybe I'm searching the wrong way...

Comment: check this out: https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_tutorials.html